# Python TKinter saving data in csv files

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, save

I've already searched for answers to similar questions on StackOverflow but I can't find a good one for my case...
My script always return this error:

```
    Avvio: python3 /...my_script.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/...my_script.py", line 243, in <lambda>
    command=lambda:save_sheet(nam, srn, brt)
TypeError: make_sheet.<locals>.save_sheet() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

to this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

def make_sheet():
    win = Tk()
    frm_win = Frame(win)
    frm_win.pack()


    surn = StringVar()
    nam = StringVar()
    brt = StringVar()

    def save_sheet():
        a_surname = surn.get()
        a_name = nam.get()
        a_birth = brt.get()


   Label(frm_win, text="Surname ", font=14).grid(row=0, column=0, ipady=3, sticky ='e')
   Entry(frm_win, textvariable=surn, width=30, justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky ='w')

   Label(frm_win, text="Name ", font=14).grid(row=1, column=0, ipady=3, sticky ='e')
   Entry(frm_win, textvariable=nam, width=30, justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky ='w')

   Label(frm_win, text="Date of birth ", font=14).grid(row=2, column=0, ipady=3, sticky ='e')
   Entry(frm_win, textvariable=brt, width=18, justify=CENTER).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky ='w')


   btn_send = ttk.Button(frm_win, text="Send", width=12, command=lambda:save_sheet(surn, nam, brt))
   btn_send.grid(row=14, column=1, sticky='w', ipady=5, pady=35)


   with open('/home/...my_script.csv', 'a') as doc_csv:
       writer_csv = csv.writer(doc_csv)
       writer_csv.writerow([a_surname, a_name, a_birth])
   doc_csv.close()


   win.mainloop()
```

So, why I can't save datas on a .csv file?
I tried a lot of "combos", bring parts of code from up to down and reverse, indenting and unindenting it but any attempt won't work.
I saw a video tutorial but I really can't undestand where I get mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code in the traceback does not match the posted code.

Answer (score -1):

Your code still won't run like this.
But you can solve your question by initialize you StringVar like this in your main method

```
surn = StringVar()
nam = StringVar()
brt = StringVar()
```

and then call the save_sheet using a lambda function to pass the arguments

```
btn_send = ttk.Button(frm_win, text="Send", width=12, command=lambda : save_sheet(surn, nam, brt))
```

If you need more information you can check out this [link](https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-lambda/) for some examples.

Comment: I did it but it won't works...

Comment: @DonPre you may suggest improvements to OP's question by editing it. It is welcomed here to help others achieve a better result by proposing your own bit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqmseB4w6NM